# call a phtml file in Layout Update XML to set title in magento

Tags: php, magento, seo, magento-1.7

i want to set page title in phtml file so i want to call this phtml file in Layout Update XML of page .i am using

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="setTitle">
<template>catalog/title.phtml</template>
</action>
</reference>
```

catalog/title.phtml is the location of my phtml file.please suggest a way to solve it.
please help...